# Suitable Capacitor

Tags: tesla-coil, spark, capacitor-charging

[image]I am wondering what voltage rating I need for the capacitor in the attached circuit. Its basically the front end of a Tesla coil. The voltage source is a neon sign transformer 3kV open circuit at up to 15ma short circuit (2kV 10ma under load), 30K Hz. 
This is what I understand about the circuit. The voltage is rectified to pulsed DC via the full wave rectifier bridge. The capacitor acts like a short circuit so the nst effectively pumps the capacitor up to the breakdown voltage of the 2nd neon lamp (90V). When the breakdown voltage is breached the capacitor unleashes a 90V spike into the inductor. I'm not sure what  roll the first neon lamp (spark gap) plays other than delivering a current rush to the capacitor.

If the AC from the nst is a sinewave the capacitor would collect about 0.182V in one pulsed DC period (t=0 to t=16.6 uS) (disregarding the effect of the first neon lamp). I'm thinking a capacitor with a voltage rating of at least 200V? 
Two Questions:
1. What is the purpose of the first neon (spark gap)?
2. Would a capacitor with a voltage rating of around 200V suffice?

Comment: What attached circuit?

Comment: I forgot to include it. Now you should see it.

Comment: You could simulate it, use a voltage activated switch in place of the neon lamp...

Comment: Good idea. However it will take a week to complete the simulation on my computer.